# What could interfere HTML table attributes?

Tags: html, html-table, cellpadding

I have the following code in a JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="10">
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
        <tr><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

That's the entire file.

It is in a JSP that gets put in an IFrame. I can't figure out what is interfering with the cellpadding value -- each value should be 10 pixels from the boundary of its table cell, but it isn't. What am I missing here?

Here's the output:

[image: output from HTML table]

Here's the relevant section from Chrome's 'inspection' window:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to diagnose anything with your browser's dev tools?

Comment: FYI: cellpadding is deprecated, and you should use CSS instead.

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: @LGSon rendered output is in the original post.

Comment: I can only see an image showing a "photo" of the output, I am looking for the actual _html_

Comment: @CameronHurd added Chrome's 'inspection' output the post

Comment: Since the _relevant_ html does not work, I'm sure the non relevant does ... meaning, it is obvious it does affect the table somehow. Please provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: Is there a CSS rule with `padding` for the `td` elements? That would override the `cellspacing` attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/93pbzgjn/

Comment: @arcy - perhaps something from the css rules portion of dev tools! The markup alone doesn't give any new info.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/lehide/1/edit?html,output (it doesn't even generate the `<div class="bodyPane">` shown in the screenshot). You need to provide a real [MCVE]